# How to pass an instance of a button to a view from a controller?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc

I was wondering if there is a way of passing a button which I have created in my controller:

```
public class AccountController : Controller
{

    public ActionResult Login()
    {
        Button button = new Button();

        return View();
    }
}
```

to my View:

```
<form method="get" action="/Account/Login">
    <h1>Login</h1>
    <div class="col2">
        <label>Username: </label>
        <input type="text" class="textEntry" name="username" value=""/>
    </div>
    <div class="col2">
        <label>Password: </label>
        <input type="password" class="textEntry" name="password" value=""/>
    </div>
    <div class="col2">
        /*PLACE BUTTON HERE*/
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: This is one of those questions that begs the question "why?". Send a viewmodel to the view and dynamically set button properties if you need to do that.

Comment: A controller shouldn't create buttons.  A button is purely an artefact of how the information is displayed/interacted with - this is the purview of the view layer.

Comment: i will be calling an object method in a different layer, and im still relatively new to this

Comment: is there a way to call the method in the different layer from the button in the view?

Comment: Please post the code of the method that you want to call.

Comment: you can call a Control method from the View - in fact that is what the action="/Account/Login" is doing

Comment: its a method which returns a boolean based on what information it has got back from an sqlrequest

Answer (score 1):

First of all: the Button's class is your own class or belongs to System.Web.UI.WebControls?
In the first case you can pass your object through viewmodel  simply writing: `return View(yourClass);`
In the second case, its use is unnatural for the model-view-controller pattern because you have to separate the logical layer from the presentation layer. 
What I strongly suggest is create an appropriate viewmodel class in order to pass at the View all you need to create (with razor or not) the button.